# How do you find what you need in iOS frameworks?

Tags: ios, frameworks

I searched for an answer to this, but perhaps the question is a bit too noob for this site--basically I'm a bit overwhelmed by all the different frameworks out there or even how to find what you need in a single framework. If I want to, say, find a way to fetch address book data into my app, how do I search for that? Is there some magic efficient way that everyone uses?

Comment: Apple documentation and search bar are there for this.

Comment: Is there a good way to search through non-Apple frameworks as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The xCode Organizer window has a documentation tab that you can search in.  Put in a keyword and it will show you refrences, example code and what framework that class is in.

Comment: Thanks! That actually helps a lot--hadn't noticed it there.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure this qualifies as an answer, but yep: Google for it. Whenever I want to learn about something new, I Google for (for example) "iOS Address Book Example". That seems to be the best way to find info on how to get into a new subject when you're not sure which framework to look in.

If you have an idea of which framework is appropriate, then the iOS documentation (both at [developer.apple.com](http://developer.apple.com) and built into xCode) is your friend.

Comment: Ty! I've been using Google so far but wasn't sure if that was the best way.

Comment: @spongefile You should accept one of the answers here if you feel your question has been resolved.

Comment: Ah ok, thought "Was this post useful to you?" did that, but just found the checkmark.

Answer (score 0):

Just found this, looks useful:
http://sazameki.jp/software/cocoa-browser-air/
I know it's just the same info you can see elsewhere, but at first glance at least the layout makes it all seem more managable.